# Python and Selenium: Deselectall() not working - StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to deselect all values from a Select with multiple="multiple" fails with the error StaleElementReferenceException. I found at that this is due to the DOM changing after deselecting the first value in the select menu. But even when I put the find element in a loop and try to deselect each value on its own, I get the same error.

```
for valueToDeselect in val_list:
    elem1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("dummyId1"))
    elem1.deselect_by_value(valueToDeselect)
```

This returns the error: `StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM`
I do not get it, why it trows an error, even though I am finding the element inside the loop.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit1**

I tried to catch the exception and try again as proposed in the comment by Gaurang Shah:

```
for valueToDeselect in val_list:
    while True:
        print("trying")
        elem1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("dummyId1"))
        elem1.deselect_by_value(valueToDeselect)
        break
    except:
        continue
```

This does not work either, it just gets stuck in the loop, printing "trying" all the time.

**Edit2**

The code for the select looks like this:

```
<select size="10" name="ErrorCodes" multiple="multiple"
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ErrorCodes\',\'\')', 0)"
id="dummyId1" title="DummyTitle1" style="width:99%;">
```

Comment: try using explicit wait for StaleElement exception, if that doesn't work out try catching this exception and retry the thing again, see if that works out. StaleElementReferenceException is pretty complex to handle sometimes and you need to hack it.

Comment: Hello Gaurang Shah, could you maybe provide an example of code of how to explicitly wait for StaleElement exception? Any help is appreciated, I have no experience with the explicit wait function.

Comment: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));`

Comment: Is your code Java-Code? I found`WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(elem1))` as described on http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html However, I get a TimeoutException and really don't know how to put his in the loop. Sorry to bother, could you maybe provide a full example of the code in the loop? Thank you!

Comment: what if you just catch the exception, is it working ?

Comment: Hello, I tried to catch the exception but it just gets stuck in the loop. Please see my Edit1 for it. Do you have any more ideas? This is really important for me.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Have you tried `deselect_all()`?: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.deselect_all

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you for the hint. I tried before and the `deselect_all()`deselects the first value in the list and then throws the same `StaleElementReferenceException`. Unfortunately I can not upload the entire HTML code but there is a javascript code in the select code, please see above **Edit2**

Comment: The id in the select is different from the id in your code. Is that a typo? Have you tried inspecting the DOM after the code deselects the first value? I sometimes have similar problems when the DOM changes in a way that I didn't expect. The "no longer attached to DOM" error can happen if you have duplicate ids, or if a DOM element is replaced just after you 'found' it.

Comment: Also, try putting `time.sleep(2)` after `elem1.deselect_by_value(valueToDeselect)`

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for your comment. I tried the time.sleep(2) approach and it did not help. The id issue was a typo. How exactly do I inspect the DOM, just by opening the source code in Firefox and check for changes? I know that that this is a rookie question, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, I was sure that would work. Does it take more than 2 seconds for the select to update after you unselect a value?

Comment: To inspect the DOM open Developer Tools by pressing F12 or selecting Developer in the main menu and then Toggle Tools. That'll let you look at the current state of the DOM, whereas opening the source code would only show you the HTML that was fetched from the server.

Comment: Hello Mark, sorry for the late reply, I was off work. The select updates really fast, definitely less than 2 seconds. I also tried with `time.sleep(10)`but it does not work either. Any more ideas?